# Plastic Bucket - Primary & Dry Hopping

Tags: off-flavor, dry-hop, primary-fermentation, bucket

I will be brewing an IPA this weekend and fermenting in a bucket...so much easier to clean afterwards.

Once fermentation is complete, I am going to dry hop for  7-10 days in the primary.  That would keep it in the bucket for about 2-2.5 weeks.

I have never kept anything in the bucket for this long (usually I would transfer)...will it produce any off flavors or is the time short enough that there is no need to worry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No problem....I go longer than that in buckets regularly.  However, dry hopping is one of the few times I still use a secondary.  There are interactions between hops and yeast that can increase flowery esters.  After experiencing that, I found that I get better dry hop character by getting the beer off the yeast before dry hopping.